# SettingBundleの特定項目をスイッチのON/OFFで動的に表示/非表示を切り替えたい

Tags: ios, xcode

iOSのアプリケーション開発で現在Setting Bundleによる、アプリ設定画面の作成を行っています。
トグルスイッチのON/OFFの切り替えで、表示されているテキストフィールドやラベルの表示のON/OFFを切り替える為には、Root.plistでどのような設定を行えばよいのでしょうか？

【作りたい動作】
・トグルスイッチ[ON/OFF]
{
 ・項目A
 ・項目B
 ・項目C
 ・項目D
}
※トグルスイッチがOFFの時は、{}内を非表示、ONの時は表示する。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「設定」アプリ内でそういう挙動を実現したい、ということですよね？
残念ながらできません。Settings Bundleによる「設定」アプリのカスタマイズは静的な構造しかつくれません。

そのような動的な挙動を実現したい場合は、自分のアプリ内にてそのような画面を作る必要があります。

Comment: 設定画面のWi-Fi設定などで質問内容の様な挙動があったので、可能かと思ったのですができないのですね。できないことが分かってスッキリしました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 良くあることですが、アップルは特別なんですよね。ずるいと思うのですが、しょうがないです。